# data from json is not displayed in ionic view

Tags: angularjs, json, ionic-framework

I'm using ionic and angularJS i retreive json in this format and i show him in the console  :

```
 "{\"id\":\"jqo1vu8225v99qt4aj1i00n7q7\",\"module_name\":\"Users\",\"name_value_list\":{\"user_id\":{\"name\":\"user_id\",\"value\":\"a4df0140-bba6-ef96-824c-57ac64b06836\"},\"user_name\":{\"name\":\"user_name\",\"value\":\"saad\"},\"user_language\":{\"name\":\"user_language\",\"value\":\"en_us\"},\"user_currency_id\":{\"name\":\"user_currency_id\",\"value\":\"-99\"},\"user_currency_name\":{\"name\":\"user_currency_name\",\"value\":\"US Dollars\"}}}"
```

And when i want to show data in the view d'ont work

Here is **my controller** :

```
'use strict';

app
.controller('visitesList', function ($scope ,$rootScope ,userProvider) {
$scope.currentUser=$rootScope.user;
console.log($scope.currentUser);

})
;
```

And here is **my view**

```
  <ion-view>
   <ion-content padding="false">
     <div class="list" ng-repeat="user in currentUser">
       {{ user.id }}
    </div>
   </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
```

Here return to me this **Error** :

*ionic.bundle.js:26794 Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: user in currentUser, Duplicate key: string:", Duplicate value: "*

What can i do ? or i should to change format of the json ?

Thank u

Comment: Does your JSON really include those backslashes etc? And Angular repeat wants objects so you should wrap the whole `$scope.currenUser` in brackets `[ ]`.

Comment: I think you will have to parse it before using it.

Comment: Yes and it is valid i checked in http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Ok, well just try making it an object. Doesn't work without removing the backslashes but I don't know how you have copy pasted the JSON in the question so it might be just that.

Answer (score 0):

Adding track by $index should solve this issue.

```
    <div class="list" ng-repeat="user in currentUser track by $index">
      {{ user.id }}
    </div>
```